# Python reads and lookup files

Tags: python, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to create a program for work that does the following:

I'm interested in converting file names from one column to their associated values in another. [Image to show a clear view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otNn7.png)

```
Pre = r"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test\pre1011"
Post = r"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test\post0522"

os.rename(Pre, Post)
```

my thoughts:
We could store each column into a list and then iterate over both of them is my general idea. creating (old, new). How can I program that? Take a column and then create a list from that, and then have a tuple that converts (X->Y)? Hopefully some of this makes sense.

Comment: 1. What Python datastructures do you know that hold (key, value) pairs? 2. If you can avoid Excel, do that. Try to use a CSV file.

Comment: Thanks for that input. A dictionary would do that. CSV file would be better. General idea would still be to convert key->value and iterate over that for each pair. But I think I could learn how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: Once you use a dictionary there is no need for iteration. That is pretty much the point of using a dict. It's straightforward to convert a properly structured CSV file to a dictionary, you can research that (there are many questions here on SO on that subject)

Comment: Brilliant thank you for that pointer! Will look deeply into CSV files. Just looking into it now and I am amazed.

Comment: Yeah that worked out a lot easier than I expected. Again, thank you!